# how to sum each rows the credit score with the condition using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

how to sum each rows the credit score with the condition that if the course does not pass, then the credit score is not counted?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckpMu.png)

example:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5yfl.png)

expected outcome:
if pass

```
df_ilkom1['sks'] = (df_ilkom['s_matdas']+df_ilkom['s_fisdas']+df_ilkom['s_pentekkin']+df_ilkom['s_pemdas']+df_ilkom['s_pengpend']+df_ilkom['s_pendag']+df_ilkom['s_pancasila']+df_ilkom['s_bindo'])
```

*first row
df_ilkom1['sks'] = 3+3+2+3+2+3+2+3  = 21 but in n_pendag = D, automatically s_pendag can't use for the input.

I was thinking like this

```
df_ilkom1['SKS'] = (df_ilkom1.loc[:, 's_matdas':'s_bindo'].sum(axis=1) - df_ilkom1.loc[:, 'n_matdas':'n_bindo'].isin(['D','E'])
```

but it sure doesn't work.

any suggestion

Comment: please provide a minimal reproducible example and the matching expected output

Comment: always put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot, not link) in question (not in comment).  It will be more readable and easier to use in answer (simpler to select and copy), and more people will see it - so more people can help you.

Comment: maybe first create column SKS` with default value - ie, `df["SKS"] = 0` - next select rows which don't have `'D','E'` in `n_pendag` and later count sum only fot these rows. Or use `apply()` to run code which use `if/else` to check value in `n_pendag`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, we have a DataFrame with a number of columns with letters (codes), and the *same* number of columns with numbers (scores). For each row we want to sum all scores, except the ones for which the corresponding code occurs in a certain list (exceptions). We can use `np.where()` to accomplish this.

Creating a sample DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import string
n=1000
letters = np.random.choice([x for x in string.ascii_uppercase[:5]], n).reshape(int(n/4),4)
numbers = np.random.randint(1,10, (int(n/4),4))

df = pd.DataFrame(np.hstack([letters, numbers]))
df.iloc[:,4:] = df.iloc[:,4:].astype(int)
df.columns = [f'code_{idx+1}' if idx < 4 else f'score_{idx-3}' for idx in range(8)]
df.head()

  code_1 code_2 code_3 code_4 score_1 score_2 score_3 score_4
0      D      C      D      D       7       7       6       2
1      D      A      C      C       9       7       4       9
2      B      D      E      A       2       3       3       9
3      D      A      A      B       6       1       6       2
4      A      A      A      E       7       6       3       9
```

Performing calculation and adding column with the result:

```
exceptions = ['D','E']
df['total_score'] = np.where(~df.loc[:,'code_1':'code_4']
                             .isin(exceptions),df.loc[:,'score_1':'score_4'], 0).sum(axis=1)
df.head()

  code_1 code_2 code_3 code_4 score_1 score_2 score_3 score_4 total_score
0      D      C      D      D       7       7       6       2           7 # summing score_2 ('C')
1      D      A      C      C       9       7       4       9          20 # summing score_2, 3, 4 ('A', 'C', 'C')
2      B      D      E      A       2       3       3       9          11
3      D      A      A      B       6       1       6       2           9
4      A      A      A      E       7       6       3       9          16
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe first you could create column `SKS` with default value

```
df['SKS'] = 0
```

next select rows which don't have `'D','E'` in `n_pendag`

```
mask = ~df['n_pendag'].isin(['D','E'])
```

and run `sum()` only on these rows

```
df['SKS'][mask] = df.loc[:,'n_matdas':'n_bindo'][mask].sum(axis=1)
```

---

Minimal working code:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'n_pendag': ['A','B','C','D','E'], 
    'n_matdas': [1,2,3,4,5], 
    'n_bindo' : [6,7,8,9,0]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['SKS'] = 0

mask = ~df['n_pendag'].isin(['D','E'])
df['SKS'][mask] = df.loc[:,'n_matdas':'n_bindo'][mask].sum(axis=1)

print(df)
```

Result:

```
 n_pendag  n_matdas  n_bindo  SKS
0        A         1        6    7
1        B         2        7    9
2        C         3        8   11
3        D         4        9    0
4        E         5        0    0
```

---

Other idea is to use `apply()` to run function with `if/else`

```
def get_sum(row):
    if row['n_pendag'] in ['D','E']:
        return 0
    else:
        return row.loc['n_matdas':'n_bindo'].sum()

df['SKS'] = df.apply(get_sum, axis=1)
```

Minimal working code:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'n_pendag': ['A','B','C','D','E'], 
    'n_matdas': [1,2,3,4,5], 
    'n_bindo' : [6,7,8,9,0]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def get_sum(row):
    if row['n_pendag'] in ['D','E']:
        return 0
    else:
        return row.loc['n_matdas':'n_bindo'].sum()

df['SKS'] = df.apply(get_sum, axis=1)

print(df)
```

---

Next idea is to use `numpy.where(condition, value_for_true, value_for_false)`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {
    'n_pendag': ['A','B','C','D','E'], 
    'n_matdas': [1,2,3,4,5], 
    'n_bindo' : [6,7,8,9,0]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['SKS'] = np.where(~df['n_pendag'].isin(['D','E']), df.loc[:,'n_matdas':'n_bindo'].sum(axis=1), 0)

print(df)
```

---

And last idea: first calculate `sum` for all rows and later put `0` in `SKS` when `'D','E'` in `n_pendag`

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'n_pendag': ['A','B','C','D','E'], 
    'n_matdas': [1,2,3,4,5], 
    'n_bindo' : [6,7,8,9,0]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['SKS'] = df.loc[:,'n_matdas':'n_bindo'].sum(axis=1)

df['SKS'][ df['n_pendag'].isin(['D','E']) ] = 0

print(df)
```